# 1920x1080 Nexus 5 Emulator isn't 1920x1080

Tags: android, libgdx

The head states everything.

When i start the emulator and render a 2D sprite/texture/image whatever you want with the dimensions similar to the emulator(1920x1080) i get following result:

[image]

As you can see, a piece of the texture has been cutting off at the right side.

If you take a closer look at the buttom right part of the whole screenshot you can see the dimensions retrieved trough libgdx:

```
screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
```

These static methods return the physical resolution of the device.

I think responsible for the less available resolution are the soft-button-bar on the right side.

Is this correct?

How can I disable this bar to get the full resolution of the device because when I google for (Nexus 5, the device specification I use for the emulator) it doesn't have such a bar on the bottom(in portrait) or on the side (in landscape-mode).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplicationConfiguration.html#useImmersiveMode https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: Oh man I wrote the whole thing just to find a related question with an answere. Should improve my search algorithm...

Comment: @Xoppa yes xoppa did see a related question immediately after posting this question. ps: like your tutorials